# How can I play video using Chewie controller after a delay in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  ChewieController? chewieController;
  _pickvideo() async{
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
      _playVideo();
    });
  }

    _playVideo(){
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlay = VideoPlayerController.asset(
      "assets/videoplayback.mp4");

  chewieController = ChewieController(videoPlayerController: _videoPlay,
      autoInitialize: true,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        return Center(
          child: Text("Error"),
        );
      });
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(children: [

          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: ()  {
              setState(()async {
                 await _pickvideo();
              });

            },
            child: Text("Play After button Pressed"),
          ),
          (chewieController!=null)?Expanded(child: Chewie(controller: chewieController!)):Text("Error Message"),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If I use a delay and called _playVideo() function, the video player is not working but if I called without a delay it's working. How can I make the video player to play after a delay.

But actually, I need a video file to be picked from storage and play it using a chewie controller. But image picker has an await keyword. The same error is occuring as delaying.

Error Appeared in terminal

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 2722): Release 8b63f91 [ExoPlayerLib/2.14.1] [generic_x86_arm, sdk_gphone_x86_arm, Google, 30] [goog.exo.core]
D/CCodecBuffers( 2722): [c2.android.aac.decoder#470:1D-Output.Impl[N]] Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 0
D/CCodecBuffers( 2722): [c2.android.aac.decoder#470:1D-Output.Impl[N]] Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 1
D/CCodecBuffers( 2722): [c2.android.aac.decoder#470:1D-Output.Impl[N]] Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 2
D/CCodecBuffers( 2722): [c2.android.aac.decoder#470:1D-Output.Impl[N]] Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 3
I/CCodecConfig( 2722): query failed after returning 19 values (BAD_INDEX)
D/CCodecConfig( 2722): c2 config diff is   c2::i32 coding.drc.compression-mode.value = 3
```

Comment: have you try Future.dealayed?

Comment: yes but not worked @AliMahdiyar

Comment: what you mean by "not worked"? do you have any crash with a stacktrace? if so, what does it look like?

Comment: @pskink I updated the error too in queastion

Comment: ok what do you want to do with `_pickvideo() async{
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
_playVideo();
});
}`? it declares local `_pickvideo` callback, nothing more

Answer (score 0):

try to increase the delay time to 800 milisecond

```
  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 800), () {
      _playVideo();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(children: [

      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await _pickvideo();
          setState(() {
             
          });

        },
        child: Text("Play After button Pressed"),
      ),
      (chewieController!=null)?Expanded(child: Chewie(controller: chewieController!)):Text("Error Message"),
    ]),
  ),
);}
```

SetState() method should be called after calling _pickvideo(). That's why the video not appeared in screen